# How to remove the member from marketing list in crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I need to remove some member(**here member represent as a lead**) from the marketing list based on some condition.How to do this using javascript?Is possible to do this?

Comment: when you ask a qestion please add the right tags, this is a question about crm 2011, so is not necessary to add the dynamics-crm-4 tag

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the message AddListMembersListRequest that is described [here](http://mileyja.blogspot.pt/2011/11/add-multiple-entities-members-to.html) with a example.

BTW in CRM Dynamics 2011 is a new feature that is Dynamic Marketing List that add and remove members automatically based in a query. Check [that](http://www.summitgroupsoftware.com/blog/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-dynamic-marketing-lists).